# CSS grid - How do you evenly distribute column width across "auto" columns?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

Say I have this layout:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto / auto 64px 80px 64px auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <div style="background-color: red">This is a test. How do I make it symmetrical?</div>
  <div style="background-color: green"></div>
  <div style="background-color: yellow"></div>
  <div style="background-color: blue"></div>
  <div style="background-color: pink"></div>
</div>
```

I'd like to force the layout to be symmetrical, regardless of content, how do I do this?

**EDIT**

This isn't a duplicate (though it looks it at first glance):

[How is "grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr auto" interpreted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49145552/how-is-grid-template-rows-auto-auto-1fr-auto-interpreted)

is about *how* `1fr` and `auto` work

[CSS Grid - can you constrain auto column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53663119/css-grid-can-you-constrain-auto-column)

is about image overflow of an auto column.

This question is about how to make a simple layout symmetrical.

Comment: *is about how 1fr and auto work* --> if you have this information then you can do your symetrical layout and make column to be equal using `1fr`

Comment: @TemaniAfif true but it didn't come up on my search (as it is a differently framed question!)

Comment: *true but didn't come up on my search* --> this isn't an issue, you didn't find it but I did so I close it as duplicate. Closing a question as a duplicate isn't a *bad* thing. Your question can know bring more search to those duplicate target.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Thanks - It's a different question in my view, but let's agree to differ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer is to use `1fr` instead of `auto`!

```css
.grid {
        display:grid;
        grid-template: auto / 1fr 64px 80px 64px 1fr;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<div class='grid'>
  <div style="background-color: red">This is a test. How do I make it symmetrical?</div>
  <div style="background-color: green"></div>
  <div style="background-color: yellow"></div>
  <div style="background-color: blue"></div>
  <div style="background-color: pink"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: more exactly it should be `minmax(0,1fr)`

Comment: @TemaniAfif, thanks - why not post as an answer, with an explanation...